# Check to ensure both textboxes match & display a label saying if they do

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

So I am trying to check two textboxes to make sure they match each other, and then in a label I want to say either "Passwords match" or "Passwords do not match".

Well, I got most of it working, but if both textboxes do not have anything in them I want the label to be visible. No matter what I try I keep getting "Passwords match" when both textboxes are empty.

So to sum it up, the user enters the password stack into both textboxes the label should read "Passwords match", but if the user deletes both passwords out of the textbox I want the label to disappear. The label I want to disappear is called 'lblPWCountAgain' and the textboxes are called 'txtPassword' and 'txtPasswordAgain'

But under the password box I have it set so it tells the user how many characters they have left to type in the textbox. This label only shows when the user focuses on the textbox so it is not visible until they focus. The "Passwords match" and "Passwords do not match" label is set the same way. And if the user enters the same password in both textboxes the background color becomes green and if they enter mismatched passwords it becomes red.

So I have set the textboxes TextChanged event to 'textbox_TextChangedCompare' by doing the following:

```
txtPassword.TextChanged += textbox_TextChangedCompare;
txtPasswordAgain.TextChanged += textbox_TextChangedCompare;
```

In the textbox_TextChangedCompare I have:

```
string pw = txtPassword.Text;
string pwa = txtPasswordAgain.Text;

if (pw == pwa)
{
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible=true;
  lblPasswordCount.Text = "Passwords Match";
  lblPWCountAgain.Text = "Passwords Match";
}

else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pw) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwa))
{
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible=false;
}

else
{
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible = true;
  lblPWCountAgain.text = "Passwords do not match!";
  var passw = txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length;
  lblPasswordCount.Text = passw.ToString();
}

// I also just tried to use this as well
if (pw == "" && pwa == "")
{
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible = false;

  var passw = txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length;
  lblPasswordCount.Text = passw.ToString();
}
```

This is the code for the focusing:

```
var password = txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length;

if (txtPassword.Focused)
{
  lblPasswordCount.Visible = true;
  lblPasswordCount.Text = password.ToString() + " Characters remaining";
}

else
{
  lblPasswordCount.Visibe = false;
}
```

So for the background color change I did this:

```
// I set the KeyUp event to textbox_Compare:
txtPassword.KeyUp += textbox_Compare;
txtPasswordAgain.KeyUp += textbox_Compare;

private void textbox_Compare(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  Color bgColor = new Color();

  if (txtPassword.Text != txtPasswordAgain.Text)
  {
  bgColor = Color.Red;
  }
  else
  {
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible = true;
  bgColor = Color.LightGreen;
  }

  if (txtPassword.Text == String.Empty && txtPasswordAgain.Text == String.Empty)
  {
    bgColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight // This is the background color of the textbox by default
  }

  txtPassword.BackColor = bgColor;
  txtPasswordAgain.BackColor = bgColor;
}
```

I am not sure if I am just repeating myself during the code or what, but I can't figure it out. It may not be the best code but I am trying to learn this as much as I can!

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

> Well, I got most of it working, but if both textboxes do not have
>   anything in them I want the label to be visible. No matter what I try
>   I keep getting "Passwords match" when both textboxes are empty.

I believe it's the order of your statements.  The first condition was evaluating to true before the statement could check for empty strings. Try the solution below where I'm checking for empty strings before checking if the textboxes are equal.

```
    string pw = txtPassword.Text;
    string pwa = txtPasswordAgain.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pw) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwa))
    {
      lblPWCountAgain.Visible=false;
//whicheverLabelIsShowing.Text = "Whatever text you want showing";
    }    
    else if (pw == pwa)
    {
      lblPWCountAgain.Visible=true;
      lblPasswordCount.Text = "Passwords Match";
      lblPWCountAgain.Text = "Passwords Match";
    } 
    else
    {
      lblPWCountAgain.Visible = true;
      lblPWCountAgain.text = "Passwords do not match!";
      var passw = txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length;
      lblPasswordCount.Text = passw.ToString();
    }

// I also just tried to use this as well
if (pw == "" && pwa == "")
{
  lblPWCountAgain.Visible = false;

  var passw = txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length;
  lblPasswordCount.Text = passw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is doing the same thing again, and this time the character count under the password textbox is staying there but that is simple to fix. When there is nothing left in the textboxes it still says "Passwords match" because technically they do! Not sure if I am redundent in the code and have it in another place and thats causing the error, I have looked but I don't see anything

Comment: If you debug the conditions, which condition evaluates to true? It doesn't look like you update the text of the label when the passwords are empty so if the text is "Passwords match" before, it will be after. See my edited post.

Comment: I have no clue how to debug the conditions to determine which one is true. But nah the code you just showed isn't working either...

Comment: From your solution, press F5 to start debugging. You set a breakpoint on a line of code using F9. Place a breakpoint inside each "if"  statement and see which one gets hit.

Comment: I am not seeing where any of it tells you if it evaluates to true. At the bottom in the "Locals" Window all it says is:

this       {PassLock.frmAddSite, Text: PassLock - Add Site}  PassLock.frmAddSite
sender {Text = "a} NOTE: THIS IS THE TEXT I ENTERED INTO THE TEXTBOX    Object {System.Windows.Forms.TextBox}
e           {System.Event Args} System.EventArgs
pw        "a"         string
pwa      ""           string

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to all of this, I have never had to do anything like this before! I tried looking it up ad it really didn't help at all.

Comment: I would look into debugging in Visual Studio. You can place breakpoints throughout your code to pause execution and check values. Using that you can see which if statement is being executed and whether some other place in your code is updating the text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to set the background color in the **KeyUp** event sink ?
Unless you have a reason to do so, just include it in the code called in the **TextChanged** event sink. 
It keeps the code simple ( i.e. less error prone ).
Try this :

```
private void ComparePasswordsAndSetControlsAccordingly() {

        Color backgroundColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight;

        if (txtPassword.Text.Length == 0 && txtPasswordAgain.Text.Length == 0) {
            // both are empty

            lblPWCountAgain.Visible = false;

            // background color is default

            lblPasswordCount.Text = "???"; // set the text to be displayed
            lblPWCountAgain.Text = "???";  // set the text to be displayed ( or leave it out : it's not visible anyway )
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Text == txtPasswordAgain.Text) {
            // they match

            lblPWCountAgain.Visible = true;
            lblPasswordCount.Text = "Passwords Match";
            lblPWCountAgain.Text = "Passwords Match";

            backgroundColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else {
            // they do not match ( one can be empty, but not both )

            lblPWCountAgain.Visible = true;
            lblPWCountAgain.Text = "Passwords do not match!";
            lblPasswordCount.Text = "???"; // set the text to be displayed
            DisplayCharactersRemaining();

            backgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }

        txtPassword.BackColor = backgroundColor;
        txtPasswordAgain.BackColor = backgroundColor;
    }
```

Just call it in the **textbox_TextChangedCompare** method.
You probably want to call it in the constructor of your form as well.

This is *DisplayCharactersRemaining* method ( call it in the code for the focusing )

```
private void DisplayCharactersRemaining() {
        lblPasswordCount.Text =
            (txtPassword.MaxLength - txtPassword.Text.Length).ToString() + " Characters remaining";
    }
```

I got rid of temporary variables and renamed the **bgColor** variable.
IMO, if you have a **lblPasswordCount** label, you should have a **lblPasswordCountAgain** label
to match, it's just more intuitive, and it matches with **txtPassword** and **txtPasswordAgain**.
Yet, since they display either the count of the remaining characters or information about password matching, they probably should have a different name altogether.
Also ( but it could be just a matter of personal taste ) I would change the foreground color rather than the background color : I find that a textbox with a red background color is a little difficult to read.